# how to do advanced printing in python with numbers and how to escape %?

Tags: python, printing, formatting

```
outLine ="%d\t%d(%3.1f%%)" % seqCount, countA, percentA
print outLine
```

I am having trouble printing this line and can't seem to see what the problem is with it.
It tells me not enough arguments for format string. Thanks for any help you can give me

Comment: If you use the new-style formatting, this wouldn't be an issue: `outLine = "{:d}\t{:d}({:3.1f}%)'.format(seqCount, countA, percentA)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argument to `%` should be single value. Use tuple in your case:

```
outLine ="%d\t%d(%3.1f%%)" % (seqCount, countA, percentA)
print outLine
```